# php artisan doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have wamp 2.5 on my windows

When I run PHP artisan command it gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\mb_internal_encoding() in C:\wamp\www\advanced-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration.php on line 43

Can you help me?

Comment: You need to give us more details, see  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Comment: Where are you running this command? Your Laravel application root?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have mbstring installed and enabled. I can't give an answer how to fix it because i do not know your platform. But if you are using a xampp/wamp server i would setup a homestead VM instead. It can be a little complicated but it is easy when you first have learned it.

Here is a good tutorial for setting up a homestead on laracasts:
[Virtual Machines and Homestead setup](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/2)